# Laravel Many to Many get collection of third instance selection

Tags: php, foreach, laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many

I am trying to grab collections form many to many relationships in my application.

To explain very quickly: Lets say I have categories that themselves have dedicated hashtags. Those hashtags again have photos.

Now, I want to grab one category and its dedicated hashtags. But I also want to grab all photos that are associated with those hashtags.

So here is what I have tried but still, this does not work:

```
 $all_related_hashtags = $categorie->hashtags()->get();

 $photos = foreach ($all_related_hashtags as $hashtag) {

        $hashtag->photos;

      }
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
@foreach ($all_related_hashtags as $hashtag)

@foreach(array_chunk($hashtag->photos, 4) as $row)

        <div class="row">

                @foreach($row as $photo)
```

**SECOND EDIT**

```
@foreach ($all_related_hashtags as $hashtag)

@foreach ($hashtag->photos as $photo)

    {{ $photo->title }}

@endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: Shouldn't you push hashtag object to a photosArray one by one in the foreach loop?

Comment: how would I have to do that?

Comment: check my answers below. hope it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
$all_related_hashtags = $categorie->hashtags()->get();

$photos = array();

foreach ($all_related_hashtags as $hashtag) {

    $photos[] = $hashtag->photos;

}
```

If you just want to display in your view the photos for each hashtag you can actually call the photos in your view using nested loop such as:

```
foreach ($all_related_hashtags as $hashtag) {
    foreach ($hashtag->photos->take($limit) as $photo){
        echo $photo->url
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a non object error as if the array does not contain any photos (I have photos in the db for sure).

Comment: Yes, the photo array is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the result you expect though, the purpose of using $photos[] instead of $photos inside the foreach loop is to assign the group of photos that belong to one hashtag into a single array block for every hashtag in the collection, so if you only assign **$photos = $hashtag->photos;** then at the end of the loop $photos will only contain the photos of the last hastag of the loop.

Comment: do you have another idea then? I will check that.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how the error occurs from the code solution above? how do you call the $photos array in your view?

Comment: I've updated the code for a simpler solution, that should work.

Comment: You have to understand that $hastag->photo will return object not array, so the array_chunk is not necessary. To access the properties of the photo your second foreach should be **foreach ($hashtag->photos as $photo)** then access the photo property like **$photo->title** etc, and remove the third foreach as well.

Comment: but I still would have to display them in rows with 4 each.

Comment: Do you mean you wanted to get only 4 photos for each hashtag? If so you should use **$hashtag->photos->take(4)** (updated the code solution)

Comment: as I mentioned in my previous comment, in your second foreach use **foreach ($hashtag->photos->take(4) as $photo)**, the function take() is similar to the SQL query LIMIT

Comment: No I think you do not fully understand what I mean. I want to display all of them but I used the 4 to display four in a row..

Comment: If that's the case then it's a matter of how you arrange your HTML and CSS elements, still using the same loop, but add a counter to break into a new line every 4 photos.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$all_related_hashtags = $categorie->hashtags()->get();

$categorie_photos = array();

foreach ($all_related_hashtags as $hashtag) {

   $current_photos = array();

   foreach ( $hashtag->photos as $photo ) {
      $current_photos[] = $photo;
   }

   array_merge($categorie_photos, $current_photos);

}
```

Comment: if I return $categorie_photos I get an empty array. (There are photos in the db for sure)